# Does PHP have an equivalent of C/C++'s #ifdef?

Tags: php, constants

I'm trying to define a constant, but I don't want to redefine it if it's already been defined. 
Here's a C sample:

```
#ifndef BASEPATH
#define BASEPATH /mnt/www
#endif
```

What is the most elegant way to do this in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

Comment: Technically, no, as PHP's `define` / `defined` are evaluated at **runtime** (PHP defines are almost the same as variables), and there is no (builtin) **preprocessor** which is capable of disabling a bunch of lines of code without evaluating its syntax correctness (for example, disabling syntactically wrong code with PHP's `if(defined(...))` wouldn't help).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`defined()`](http://php.net/defined) and [`define()`](http://php.net/define).

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    define('BASEPATH', '/mnt/www');
}
```

Comment: Nice! What I've settled on is this (all in one line): `defined('BASE_PATH') || define('BASE_PATH', '/mnt/www/');` If `defined()` is **true**, the rest of the conditional never gets evaluated, if `defined()` returns **false**, the second half of the conditional is evaluated and `BASE_PATH` gets defined.

Answer (score 7):

```
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    define('BASEPATH', '/mnt/www');
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

Answer (score 6):

In C, #ifdef often involves writing/enabling/disabling custom code based on whether a define exists or not.  Though the OP was not looking for the answer that follows, search engine users may be interested to get an expanded answer.  (This question helped me RTM to find the answer that follows.)

If one has a .php file that is included multiple times, it can be convenient to declare a  function only if it was not already declared by a prior include of the same file.  Convenience, in this case, is keeping tightly-related code in the same file instead of having to put it in a separate `include_once` .php file and unnecessarily separate code that is not meant to be generally re-used in other contexts (files).

Since it seems wasteful/improper to re-declare functions multiple times, it turns out that an #ifdef-like construct in PHP is possible:

```
if (! function_exists('myfunc'))
{
  function myfunc(...)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Where `...` indicates your fill-in-the-blank.

See also: [function_exists (PHP 4, PHP 5)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) (w/ comments).

Comment: It appears that global variables are not visible from within myfunc(), so references have to be passed in as arguments (as needed).

Comment: Yes, I had a semi-colon at the end of the if statement (and it is now gone) but the `...` are clearly described in the body of the answer. The code is a copy/paste of something on a real web site, only I replaced arguments and function body with `...` and changed the function name.

Comment: I don't even mention that the sketch makes no sense: "if one function doesn't exist - define a function with another name" :-S

Comment: it's not a proofreading, it's pointing on your issues. Well, this still is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Are you trying to say that someone searching for "php" "ifdef" would not find this helpful, or are you saying people should not answer questions based on the fact that the answer doesn't exactly fit the detail text of the question.  This question was key to my solving the problem of conditionally declaring functions.  It seemed thoughtful to expand the answers to help more seekers.

Comment: the issue here that you're trying to give some name to this solution like "conditionally declaring functions". But the fact is - it's just `if` (which is trivial), `function_exists()` - which is rtfm, and function declaration - which is trivial as well. Programming is not a casting some magic spells, it's logical process. So if you separated your issue of creating "conditionally declared functions" -you would come to the question-"how to get if function with name `foo` is declared" and you'd find it easily yourself in documentation. But, indeed, decomposition is a way too difficult to newbies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16477/discussion-between-kbulgrien-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 4):

Use [defined()](http://php.net/defined) function

```
if(!defined("constantname")) {
   define("constantname", "value");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is condensed rewriting of Radu's answer above (and everyone else's).

```
defined('BASE_PATH') || define('BASE_PATH', '/mnt/www/');
```

That's it. If **`defined('BASE_PATH')`** evaluates to **true**, the rest of the conditional never gets evaluated. If it returns **false**, the second half of the conditional is evaluated and `BASE_PATH` gets defined.

Comment: I recommend the longer version, even if on one line, since the added readability will be beneficial in the long run... `if (!defined('BASE_PATH')) define('BASE_PATH', '/mnt/www/');` is only *3 characters* longer than this condensed version, and it more than makes up for it in readability.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**defined()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php):

```
<?php
/* Note the use of quotes, this is important.  This example is checking
 * if the string 'TEST' is the name of a constant named TEST */
if (defined('TEST')) {
    echo TEST;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

use [require_once()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) to include a file once: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: Question was asked over ten years ago and, while I know little about C or C++, a quick search of the function they mentioned has nothing to do with requiring a file.