# how to include a php file that already includes another file?

Tags: php, php-include

I am trying to include 2 php file in two separate `<td>` tags in the same table.

```
<td><?php include 'login.php';?> </td>
<td><?php include 'register.php';?> </td>
```

Both the php files include another php file for connecting to a database (eg. `<?php include 'database.php';?>`

Now, the problem is, the second file doesn't show up in the table. First file works.

Php files work independently. No problem with the code.

I removed the include in 1.php and everything worked fine - ie. both the files show up in table.

My conclusion is, it goes on including indefinitely. Now, how do I solve this?

regards
Ganesh Kumar

Comment: `require_once($file)`

Comment: Thanks. tried it. It didn't work. include_once was also tried.

Comment: Did you do it on all of them? Something tells me you did not do it on the include inside each file as well.

Comment: Yep, You are right. I changed it in all the files and now it worked . Thanks :-)

Comment: You might do a conditional include of some function or entity in the included file.  For example, see my answer, or other answers in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538601/does-php-have-an-equivalent-of-c-cs-ifdef question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [include-once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php#function.include-once)

> The `include_once` statement includes and evaluates the specified file
>   during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the
>   include statement, with the only difference being that if the code
>   from a file has already been included, **it will not be included again**.
>   As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

i.e.:

```
 include_once('database.php');
 include_once('login.php');
 include_once('register.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have several options, now that I think about it.

### Require_once:

```
require_once('database.php')
```

This is the most accepted method for files such as this one that you describe, as it will hard-fail if the file cannot be included. For files that do program instantiation (I.e. database connection) this method is preferred.

### Include_once:

```
include_once('login.php')
```

I've never found a reason to use this statement over `require_once`; however, that said, it doesn't mean there isn't one. If you have a file that does some instantiation of something related to your programme that isn't mission-critical, then you could suppose to use this directive over the other.

### Define Include Constants:

This method requires a bit more explanation: instead of starting your included file (`database.php` in our example) off with the code for it, start it off in a manner similar to C/C99/C++.

```
<?php
    if (!defined("INCLUDED_DATABASE"))
    {
        define("INCLUDED_DATABASE", true);

        // add main body of file here
    }
?>
```

This method basically accomplishes the same thing as the `include_once` and `require_once`, except that *in no circumstances* will it ever actually process the body twice in one request, even if you forget to use `_once` as a suffice to your `include`/`require` method. This goes back to the old days of C/C99/C++
where including a file twice would hard-fail the compiler, as duplicate definitions would take place.

---

Personally, I have always preferred the last option: it's the most strict. Yes, `require_once` and `include_once` when used diligently will have the same effect, but suppose someone (not even *you* necessarily) is modifying the application and accidentally does an `include` or `require` without the `_once` suffix, they will be having a bad day. This method prevents that.

That said, I still use a `require_once` when necessary, and a `require` if it can be included multiple times. (Files with that designation are not designed with the `define` construct.)